# C# and MySQL - string replacement

Tags: c#, mysql

This is mostly me trying to read C# (I know Python, PHP and Javascript, but I'm new to C#)

It also may be MySQL that I am trying to interpret here.

I've got this section of code:

```
 sql_query = "insert into peer_review_info " +
          " (review_id, emp_id, comments_positive, comments_negative )" +
          " values(?review_id, ?employeeid, ?strength, ?weakness) ";
    myCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql_query, connection);            
    Trace.Write("strength = ", strength );
    Trace.Write("areaofimprovement = ", areaofimprovement);
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?review_id", ViewState["review_id"].ToString()));
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?employeeid", ViewState["employeeid"].ToString()));
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?strength", strength));
    myCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?weakness", areaofimprovement));
```

I am wondering about what the `?` in the sql_query value section means (is that a C# way of determining variables or is that something I'm not aware of for MySQL syntax).

I am also wondering if my understanding of this section is correct - it is more or less just a SQL insert statement, followed by a definition of the variables in question. Am I right about that?

Comment: It's the preparation of a MySql command and setting of parameters in the query, the command isn't run in this snippet.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing to do with C# specifically, they're just named parameters for the query. The same like you would use (read: should be using) in PDO/MySQLi when you're writing PHP.

Also note that this isn't string replacement, it's a prepared statement which allows parameters to be passed to it. You can think of a prepared statement more like a method call with it's parameters predefined, rather than writing one long string of data (which is open up to potential injection) to the database for execution directly.

Comment: You were 23 seconds faster :)